# Parse strings into four parts

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet in which there is a column containing a specific string. I need to extract all parts of that string in other columns.

**.AN150417C65**  ...........AN......150417......C......65

**.TLT150417C129**...   ... TLT.....    150417....  C.....  129

**.QQQ150417C106**    .....QQQ .  150417.....  C ... 106

**.SBNY150619C145**   ....SBNY   150619.....  C ... 145

**.JAZZ150619C195**   .....JAZZ   . 150619 .... C ... 195

**.IBB150402P340**   ....... IBB  . ... 150402 ... P ... 340

**.IBB150410P337.5**  .....IBB ....   150410 .... P  ....337.5

note that always there is a "C" or a "P" and also at the beginning of the string there is a point (which I won't need)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: VBA or Formula? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: If sizes of each sub-string are not stable you will probably need to use a RegEx.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  This is not a codewriting service.  But we will be glad to help you with your code or formulas that you have attempted to use.  Please see the HELP pages for information as to [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I was trying RIGHT () Function and LEFT () Function to extract both ends of the string, but since those not always have the same length, I'm not getting what I need.

Comment: You'll need to use `FIND` or `SEARCH` to determine the starting and ending points.

Comment: Also there is a constant, which is to extract the first letters ( they vary from 2 to 5 characters), then the next 6 numbers (they are always 6), then the following letter and finally the rest of the numbers... The only problem is that I don't know ho to put all this in a formula.

Comment: Ack! I couldn't help myself, and now we've become a code writing service. Bad me.

Comment: I do it all the time too Freeman; what are we going to do at work when we finish our code x.x still have to at least complain about it though c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These work for your example data.

Not sure what else you have but hopefully this gets you on the right track:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("1",A1)-1) 
=MID(A1,Find("1",A1),6) 
=MID(A1,Find("1",A1)+6,1) 
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-(FIND("1",A1)+6))
```

Edit:

If you need to remove the leading period, the first formula becomes:

```
=MID(A1,2,FIND("1",A1)-2)
```

[image: Results]

Comment: What happens if that 6-digit string doesn't begin with a `1`?

Comment: "These work for your example data." but yes, it relies on the first digit of the number.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your values are in cells `A1:A7` then this code will strip out the component parts and place them in columns B to E:

```
Sub SplitCodeIntoParts()
    Dim regEx As Object, matches As Object, str As String, cl As Range

    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    regEx.Pattern = "([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z])(([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)|[0-9]+))"
    regEx.Global = True
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True

    For Each cl In Range("A1:A7")

        str = VBA.Right$(cl, VBA.Len(cl) - 1)
        Set matches = regEx.Execute(str)

        If matches.Count <> 0 Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1) = matches.Item(0).SubMatches(0)
            cl.Offset(0, 2) = matches.Item(0).SubMatches(1)
            cl.Offset(0, 3) = matches.Item(0).SubMatches(2)
            cl.Offset(0, 4) = matches.Item(0).SubMatches(3)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a formula, it's going to be ugly.  Something like this to get you started:

First, add a hidden column (I'm going with B for the example) with:

`=Right(A1, Len(A1) - 1)` to get rid of the leading period, then

`=IF(IsText(Left(B1,5)),"You have a 5 character code, do 5 character stuff here",If(IsText(Left(B1,4)), "You have a 4 character code", If(IsText(left(b1,3)),"You have a 3 character code", if(IsText(Left(b1,2)),"You have a 2 character code", If(IsText(Left(B1,1)),"You have a 1 character code","You don't have any leading characters)))))`

Then start filling in the text strings with the appropriate processing for what to do in those conditions.

It will be big, ugly and very difficult to trouble shoot, so write one small piece at a time.

Answer (score 0):

So, this isn't the prettiest code ever written, but AFAIK it should do the job.  Let me know if it doesn't work.  This is assuming the strings are starting at Col A, row 1:

```
Sub Separate()
Dim parsePart As String, cel As Range, word As String, currCharacter As String, nextCharacter As String, prevCharacter As String
Dim j As Integer, i As Integer, value As Range, valueRow As Integer, valueCol As Integer, lastRow As Integer, k As Integer

'  Assuming the list of words is in Column A, starting at Row 1
lastRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
For Each value In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).Cells
    i = 0
    parsePart = ""
    prevCharacter = ""
    currCharacter = ""
    nextCharacter = ""
    valueRow = value.Row
    valueCol = value.Column
    Set cel = Cells(valueRow, 1)
    Debug.Print cel
    word = cel.value

    With cel.value
        For j = 2 To Len(word) ' starting with the second character in the string - skipping the decimal
            currCharacter = Mid(word, j, 1)
            nextCharacter = Mid(word, j + 1, 1)
            ' Check to see if the current character is same type as next, if so, move on. Otherwise,
            ' print the current string to a new cell
            If (IsNumeric(currCharacter) And Not IsNumeric(prevCharacter)) _
                Or (Not IsNumeric(currCharacter) And IsNumeric(prevCharacter)) Or nextCharacter = "" Then
                    If nextCharacter = "" Then parsePart = parsePart & "" & currCharacter
                    i = i + 1
                    Cells(value.Row, valueCol + i).value = parsePart
                    parsePart = ""
            End If
            Debug.Print currCharacter
            If Not IsNumeric(currCharacter) Then
                parsePart = parsePart & "" & currCharacter
                Debug.Print "Parsed word so far is: " & parsePart
            ElseIf IsNumeric(currCharacter) Then
                parsePart = parsePart & "" & currCharacter
                Debug.Print "Parsed word so far is: " & parsePart
            End If
            prevCharacter = currCharacter
        Next j
    End With
Next value
End Sub
```

Edit: Run the code and it'll separate the data int col. B, C, D, E, etc.

And I also didn't know you could do RegEx in VBA - learned something new today!

Comment: `RegEx` can be a useful approach when the pattern isn't trivial. It's worth having an appreciation of the technique so at least you know what is possible when faced with a pattern matching task. Glad you are learning from the site!